# how to get child node from text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

can you please tell how to get child node from text.Actually i am able to get child when user click the node and get the value of child's  using this

```
alert("node_children: " + data.node.children);
```

But now I have some  button "get child" in which I will take static text "a" and "b" i need to get child when I click "child" button of "a" and "b" using only text ?
http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/12/

```
$('#home').click(function () 
{
    var rootChildren = $('#tree').find('ul > li');
    $(rootChildren).each(function(index, item)
    {
        console.log(item.id); 
    });
});
```

I am able to get Id's not text ?

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/11/)

Comment: text nodes have no children, what are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i just want all text

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans please chck my update I am able to get id's .now I want text form that

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans anwer should same because they text and id are same

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans sorry i think i ask two question at one time

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans text nodes have no children ? "b" node have two children

Comment: i just want i click "get child" it give child of "b" output "b-a","b-b"

Comment: It's a good idea update your question will all this extra information, and just delete all those comments, instead of having six comments about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 $('#child').click(function () {
         alert('child of b');

    });
```

to

```
     $('#child').click(function () {
alert($('#tree').jstree(true).get_node('b').children);
    });
```

Comment: After some experimentation with this crazy API, I finally got it to display the text instead. I don't know if there is a cleaner method [link]http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/37/

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```
 $('#child').click(function (e) {
     alert($('#tree').jstree('get_selected')[0])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something, or could this be as simple as using

```
 console.log(item.text());
```

Instead of

```
console.log(item.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the API you can use

```
$.jstree._reference('#tree').get_text(node);
```